# Write c++ regular expression to match a #include preprocessing directive

Tags: c++, regex, include

I want to write a regular expression in c++ to match a #include preprocessing directive.
So I wrote this:

```
std::regex includePattern("^[[:blank:]|[:space:]]*#[[:blank:]|[:space:]]*include[[:blank:]|[:space:]]+[<|\"]{1}[_[:alpha:]]+[_[:alnum:]]*");
```

This is worked for:

```
std::string matchString = "#include <vector>";
```

But only matches parts of the string excluded the trailing ">", 
but if I change the regex to this:

```
std::regex includePattern("^[[:blank:]|[:space:]]*#[[:blank:]|[:space:]]*include[[:blank:]|[:space:]]+[<|\"]{1}[_[:alpha:]]+[_[:alnum:]]*[>|\"]{1}");
```

It just won't give me the desired result, just tell me "not found" ! Is there anything wrong?

Can anybody help me to write an accurate regular expression in c++ to match a #include preprocessing directive?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using an or or `[[:space:]]` and `[[:blank:]]` is senseless: everything matching `[[:blank:]]` is also matched by `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: Also, there's no point in putting `{1}` after the character classes; that's the default.

Comment: And you shouldn't put the `|` in the character class.  A character class _is_ an or; within the character class, the `|` is treated literally.  (None of which explains why your second expression didn't work.)

Comment: `#includes` could be obscured, hidden in comments `/*  */`. Unless you handle comments at the same time you will never know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on whether the input to be matched may contain new
lines?  `[[:space:]]` will match any white space, including new
lines, `[[:blank:]]` will match any white space except new lines
(and I'm not sure it is supported by the standard).  Anyway,
something like:

```
"^\\s*#\\s*include\\s+[<\"][^>\"]*[>\"]\\s*"
```

should do the trick, but...

- If your source has new lines where it shouldn't, it still
  might match.
- If your source has escaped new lines, say in the middle of the
  token `include` or the file name, it won't match.  (This is
  legal C++, but no one in their right mind would do it.)
- If your source has mismatched delimiters, a `"` at one end,
  and a `<` or a `<` at the other, it will still match.
- And it doesn't handle comments at the end of line.  Handling
  C++ style comments (`//`) should only be a matter of adding
  `"(?://.*)?"` to the end of the expression.  Handling C style
  comments (particularly since there can be several) is a bit more
  complicated.

To ensure that the delimiters match, you'd probably have to put
everything after the include in an or:

```
"^\\s*#\\s*include\\s+(?:<[^>]*>|\"[^\"]*\")\\s*"
```

Again, you'd need to add to the end to handle comments.

Comment: The 3rd `[:space:]` needs extra layer of `[` and `]`, and I think you should fix the escaping of `"`.

Comment: @nhahtdh I spotted the problem with `[:space:]` shortly after posting, and corrected it to use the much simpler `\\s`.  I've just corrected the second expression to use `\\s` as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to capture the type of inclusion `<` or `"` and the included file name you could use:

```
std::string reg = "\\s*#\\s*include\\s*([<\"])([^>\"]+)([>\"])"; // escaped version
```

**- or -**

```
std::string raw = R"reg(\s*#\s*include\s*([<"])([^>"]+)([>"]))reg"; // raw string version
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lT7oM6/1)

```
Group 1 = `<` or `"`
Group 2 = file name
Group 3 = `>` or `"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't validating are you ?
One thing, you might be able to count on include's coming after the BOL and possible spaces.
And delimited on its right side with a whitespace.
Other than that, I wouldn't try to validate whats on the right of that.

Using *Multi-line* modifier only -
`"(?m)^[^\\S\\r\\n]*#include[^\\S\\r\\n]+(.*?)[^\\S\\r\\n]*"`

Expanded:

```
 (?m)
 ^ [^\S\r\n]* 
 \#include
 [^\S\r\n]+ 
 ( .*? )               # (1)
 [^\S\r\n]*
```

Answer (score -1):

The following regex will match `#include` directives such as `#include <vector>`

```
^#include\s+<\w+>$
```

Note: this won't include directives such as `#include stdio.h`.

Comment: It also won't work for any user headers (at least typically).

Comment: @JamesKanze This is true. OP only provided one example to validate, so I tried to make it as simple as possible while meeting the example provided.